# Как мне вывести отсортированные данные из нейросети?

Tags: python, keras

У меня есть нейросеть которая классифицирует текст. Как мне вывести данные которые она отсортировала в формате "КЛАСС" : "ТЕКСТ"?
Я думаю, что проблема связана с незнанием синтаксиса keras. Возможно есть метод вроде print, чтобы вывести результат обработки.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я считаю, что мой вопрос связан больше с синтаксисом библиотеки Keras, по этому задал вопрос так обобщенно. @MaxU

Comment: Но ведь у вас есть тексты, которые поступают на вход и есть результаты работы сети. Количество первых должно совпадать с количеством вторых. Берёте через zip их объединяете, итерируетесь и выводите

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за ответ) я уже нашел примерно такое же решение

Comment: @Konsul_557, будет круто, если вы напишите ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

вообще, все оказалось просто. нужно было просто взять данные из sequences и детокенизировать их обратно в текст с помощью `tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(sequences)`
после этого сопоставить результаты из кода выше с `np.argmax(model_cnn.predict(x_test), axis=-1)`
так как данные не изменились всё сходится.
p.s. возможно я как то запутанно или непонятно написал, извините.